# Call Phone number using whatsapp IOS

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

Hello im new to ios development and currently need to call whatsapp phone number from my contact list fetched using `Contact Framework`

i have read that back then there is `abid` by using `AdresssBook` framework, the app can open specific whatsapp contact, but i also read on [Whatsapp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013)
there is no `abid` support for URL scheme, is it still possible to call phone number or open specific chat via whatsapp ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/interact-with-whatsapp-from-ios-application/

According to documentation I don't think you can make a call through custom whatsapp app scheme.They support currently only "text" parameter.

```
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
}
```

Comment: at present there is no api found in whatsapp, so we can do upto  open the particular number, but we can't do the call directly

Comment: thank you for responding, now im sure calling is not possible!